# Jquery 1.10 ajax file upload formdata issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, form-data

I know this has been asked a lot....but none of the answers I am coming across are helping.
This is something ive done many times before...but on this occasion, im hitting a problem.

Im am trying to upload a zip file, via ajax, without submitting the form, just the field. I append the file to the formdata object...but the formdata is always empty (checking it before i send via ajax).
$_FILES array server side is also always empty.

Can anyone see whats wrong, ive tried many variations...
If i console.log(jQuery("#file_import")[0].files[0]);  I see the file data.

```
                var fileInput = jQuery("#file_import")[0];
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("zipfile",fileInput.files[0]);

                jQuery.ajax("/whatever/url", {
                    method: "POST",
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    onSuccess: function(response){
                        alert("whatever...");
                    }
                });
```

Thanks in advance.
Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "the formdata is always empty," are you trying to check it using `formdata.entries()`, or are you using `formData.get('zipfile')`? I think only the second of these will work.

EDIT: here is my exact code, client and server side.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#start').click(function() {
        var fileInput = $("#file_import")[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("zipfile",fileInput.files[0]);

        $.ajax("test.php",{
            method: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(response){
                $('#output').html(response);
            }
        });
    });


});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="file" id="file_import"/>
<button id="start">Start</button>
<div id="output">
</div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

print_r($_FILES);
$t = $_FILES['zipfile'];

$date = new DateTime();
$d = $date->format('Y-m-d_H-i-s');

move_uploaded_file($t['tmp_name'], "asdf_$d.zip");

?>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I removed that line, tested in firefox, my usual browser...and $_FILES was still empty server side.
Switched to chrome...and get the same  :(

Comment: I can confirm that formData.get('zipfile') gives me the filename...but serverside $_FILES is still empty.

Comment: Just posted all my code...works on firefox/chrome, with apache/php web server.